# Getting photo from array by path with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to show images from array by they path but getting error

`App.js:44 Uncaught nc (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_location')`

I know that I must do something with promises, async functions etc., but I don't understand at all. So below is code example

```
const fireBaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(fireBaseApp);

function App() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  const listRef = ref(storage, "/");
  
  //getting all images from the bucket
  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(listRef).then((res) => {
      res.items.forEach(async (item) => {
        await setUrl((arr) => [...arr, item]);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  //Trying to download image from array with its' path
  useEffect(() => {
    const func = async () => {
      const download = ref(storage, url[2]._location.path_);
      await getDownloadURL(download).then((x) => {
        setItem(x);
      });
    };
    func();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <img src={item} />
    </>
  );
}
```

So can anybody explain please how to do it properly. Thank you !

Comment: As the Error message says: `url[2]._location` cannot be read, because `url[2]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @b2m9 I know it but before there you can find useEffect that must to fill array url

Comment: Doesn't matter, because you only fill `url` in a callback, hence _after_ your second `useEffect` runs. The way you set up your data loading in your component doesn't work. Consider either loading the pictures in the callback for `listRef` or make the second `useEffect` depend on `url` and test whether you the values you need.

Comment: @b2m9 I did dependency on url in second useEffect, so it became more wired than before :D I get image which i want but I have the same error but 2 times in a row, I can't leave it like that even though I get result that I want :D Have you any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `url[2]` to the `useEffect` dependency array. But also check if it's set before running the async func. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(url[2]){
    const func = async () => {
      const download = ref(storage, url[2]._location.path_);
      await getDownloadURL(download).then((x) => {
        setItem(x);
      });
     };
    func();
  }
}, [url[2]]);
```